# Choose combination when the thumbnail is clicked

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In product detail page, when a user clicks to thumbnail bottom of the image, instead of zooming, I want to make the first assigned combination to be selected.

I'm using default theme, with Prestashop 1.6.x

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop the fancybox from opening on thumbnail click, you have to edit the following file in your PrestaShop store:

/themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl

Search for:

```
<li id="thumbnail_ (it has child <a> tag)
```

Remove the 'fancybox' class from its child  tag and also hard code the href to javascript://

Now in order to choose the associated combination, you have to send an ajax request to fetch the associated combination ID and then use jQuery to set it on the product page. You need to change the value of following hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_product_attribute" id="idCombination" value="" />
```